# Tksheet width parameter not changing width?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to edit the width of a tksheet object.

```
self.entries = tksheet.Sheet(parent=self.rightFrame,
                                 show_header=False,
                                 show_row_index=False,
                                 width=80000000)
```

despite clearly editing the width of the table, the width will not change.

Can anyone explain what the width parameter does?

Comment: tksheet isn't part of tkinter. Is it a third party library or your own proprietary code? What does the documentation have to say about the width parameter?

Comment: The `width` and `height` are effective only when both options are given.